# mask exit 1 on gitlab ci script function failure

Tags: function, yaml, exit, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We know that, by default, gitlab ci runners uses `set -o pipefail`, as explained in [coderwall.com](https://coderwall.com/p/fkfaqq/safer-bash-scripts-with-set-euxo-pipefail) this particular option sets the exit code of a pipeline to that of the rightmost command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands of the pipeline exit successfully.

We all use the "|| true" statement to prevent a gitlab ci job from failing on a real exit 1 (to allow post process failure), for example if my `grep` makes an exit 1 but I consider this as normal and therefore I don't want my job to fail i write:

```
job:
  script:
    - grep "a" myfile.txt || true
```

But when i use functions instead of commands or scripts, it did not work anymore :(

working example with script (giving me exit 0):

```
job:
  script:
    - echo "exit 1" > test
    - chmox u+x test
    - test || true
```

working example with command (giving me exit 0):

```
job:
  script:
    - exit 1 || true
```

non working example with function (giving me exit 1):

```
job:
  script:
    - function test { exit 1; }
    - test || true
```

non working example with function (giving me exit 1):

```
job:
  script:
    - function test { exit 1; }
    - (test || true)
```

I don't understand what the difference in processing an exit code is between a script, a command or a function.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

finally it is not a problem of behavior of the functions but an error on the management of the return code of a function, indeed it is necessary to use `return` instead of `exit` in order to guarantee the same functioning as a command.

The solution was therefore very simple, in the case of a function i have to write:

```
job:
  script:
    - function test { return 1; }
    - test || true
```

Now exit code is 0 :)